# Mapnik/Python Compatibility

Tags: python, mapnik

Anyone know what versions of Python Mapnik is compatible with?

I'm having trouble getting Mapnik to work. I'm thinking it might be because I am on 64-bit Win 7 and installed the 64-bit Python (v2.7)

I looked on the Mapnik docs/wiki but didn't find any info. Any thoughts? Will Mapnik only work with 32-bit Python? Is there a 64-bit Mapnik (couldn't see it).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mapnik in general works fine with both 32bit and 64bit python versions 2.4 -> 3.2 (on linux and mac osx). On Windows, however the most recent binaries available are for Mapnik 0.7.1, and those binaries only provide the python bindings compiled against 2.5 and 2.6. So, 2.7, whether 32 or 64bit will not work for those binaries.

We plan to provide new windows Mapnik binaries that are 64 bit ready for more recent python versions when Mapnik 2.1 is released, but not for Mapnik 2.0 because our developer who knows windows is not available atm.

Comment: Must be something different. When I try the test import I still get the same error: "%1 is not a valid Win32 application". Oh well, I will keep trying...

Comment: v2.6.6 in 32-bit seems to solve the problem.